# read and modify tab delimited file

Tags: c#, csv

I need to read and then write out the record of the current record I am on.

This is the code I have so far:

```
private void ShipRecords()
{
  using (TextReader tr = File.OpenText(appSettings.CreditCardTranFile))
  {
    var strLine = string.Empty;
    string[] arrColumns = null;
    while ((strLine = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
      arrColumns = strLine.Split('\t');
      if (arrColumns[0] == "A")
      {
        if (PublishRecord(arrColumns))
        {
          arrColumns[0] = "P";
          // I need to save here
        }

      }
    }
    tr.Close();
  }
}
```

How do I write the record back out at this point with my changes?

Comment: That looks tab delimited, no?

Comment: Just create a TextWriter/StreamWriter before reading it, and at that point call WriteLine... Actually  you probably want to do this at the end of the While loop (inside) for each line you read, modified or not, to a new file

Comment: mind giving me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I didn't test this because I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but something like this.. This is how I would do it.

```
private void ShipRecords()
    {
        StreamWriter writer;
        StreamReader reader;

        try
        {
            writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile);
            reader = new StreamReader(inputFile);

            string line;
            string[] columns;

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                columns = line.Split('\t'); // you may want to check that you get the correct number of columns etc.

                if (columns[0] == "A" && PublishRecord(columns))
                    columns[0] = "P";

                writer.WriteLine(String.Join("\t", columns));
            }
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            try { writer.Close(); }
            catch { }
            try { reader.Close(); }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

I would recommend that you avoid using that Hungarian-Case style.

Comment: so the input and output file are two different files?

Comment: @ErocM Yes, in this case I am using different files. It is possible to modify the file in place too. I thought it may be simpler and perhaps better to use different files. If you use the same file, you would have to open the file first with a FileStream, then create a StreamReader/StreamWriter from that stream, then after reading, I believe seek backwards, and re-write that record. I dunno, I'd use two files unless there is a good reason you cannot. After you are done, you can always swap the files out.

Comment: rather small, at the most it'd be 100 records

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's an option but you could also change the signature of the method to return an

```
IEnumerable<string>
```

and use

```
yield return "stringValue";
```

in your loop.
The caller could then handle the writing in a regular foreach loop.